# Offline Application Cache iOS - Database Calls Not Working

Tags: caching, local-storage, local, offline-caching

My offline app works great for the most part.

- I see my files have been cached in preferences > Safari.
- I added this to my .htaccess file:

  > AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
  >
  > AddType text/cache-manifest appcache manifest
  >
  > AddType text/cache-manifest appcache
  >
  > AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
- My cache.manifest file is complete with all perimeters filled in.

My app launches fine, but when I try to hit the first button to continue, it tries to save data to local storage and fails to allow me to continue.  If I turn my Wi-Fi on and use my offline app it works.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

It turns out you cannot have  tags in your offline app.  I had to put my form in as a div and use an onclick.